# Autowired TextEncryptor

Tags: security, encryption, autowired

```
public class Crypt {

   private String textToWorkWith = null;
   @Autowired
   private TextEncryptor encryptor;

   public Crypt(){}

   public String encrypt() throws NullPointerException {
    if(this.textToWorkWith != null){
        return encryptor.encrypt(this.textToWorkWith);
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException();         }
    }
}
```

currently when I tru to call encrypt() it throws a NPE because the encryptor is null. How do I specify key to use? I was told to use an environmental variable called ENCRYPTION_KEY but don't know any way to accomplish that.

Currently I do:

```
public class Crypt{
.
.
.
private static String salt = null;
public Crypt(){
    if(this.salt == null) { //If there is no salt...

        String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey(); //Generate a salt
        this.salt = salt;
    }
    this.password = "letMeIn"; //Generate password

}
```

and then

```
TextEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.text(this.password, this.salt);
```

inside Crypt.encrypt(). But I was told that I should "Autowire TextEncryptor" so I made the above changed and it's always null now. I know that I need to specify the encryption key to use but I don't know how.

Comment: Pleas provide use mor information, i.e. spring context, how is the bean for Crypt class defined in spring context?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7ZpevuqM if you look at lines 32 and 41. 

Specifically I was told "By autowiring in the TextEncryptor Interface with Spring you don’t need to worry about the salt.
 
    @Autowired
    TextEncryptor te;
"

and 

"
We are using the org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor and the default implementation. We set the environment variable  ‘ENCRYPTION_KEY’ and let Spring handle it from there
"

I want to implement the spring environmental variable and autowire the text encryptor.